# itextSharp: Mistake in Loading XMP in PDF with C#

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp to load the XMP in PDF file

Reference: [Is it possible to load XMP file in PDF using iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284602/is-it-possible-to-load-xmp-file-in-pdf-using-itextsharp)

From above instruction I am loaded XMP data in PDF file, but there is one problem

In keywords section **"; "** *semicolon and single space* added in prefix by default as show below in screen shot.

**PDF Properties Window:**
[image]

**XMP Sample I used to load:**
[image]

I used source code to sort out this problem but I can't, still i am searching only. Before I would like to let you know to iTextSharp author, so only am posting this question.

**Note:**

In case I am setting Keywords dictionary by

```
Dictionary<String, String> info = reader.Info;
info.Add("Keywords", ",key1; key2");
```

It working fine.

Comment: Which version of iText are you using?

Comment: I'm the original iText developer and I was able to reproduce your problem by creating an XMP file that wasn't complete. This problem also occurred with XMP files created with iText versions prior to iText 5.5.0. Since iText 5.5.0, this problem was solved.

Comment: I was tried in v-5.4.3.0 and v-5.5.1.0

Comment: Yeah, but the problem isn't caused by iText. It's caused by the way you create your XMP.

Comment: oh k fine Bruno, but i have some suggestion see below comment in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably caused by the XMP file you are adding. Adobe Reader is adding extra stuff to the keywords you define in the `<dc:subject>` based on what is present or missing in the `pdf:Keywords` attribute.

Please take a look at this example: [xmp_metadata_added.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part3/chapter12/xmp_metadata_added.pdf)

This is what the XMP file looks like:

```
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.1.0-jc003">
  <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"
        xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
      dc:format="application/pdf"
      pdf:Keywords="Metadata, iText, PDF"
      pdf:Producer="iTextÂ® 5.5.1 Â©2000-2014 iText Group NV (AGPL-version); modified using iTextÂ® 5.5.1 Â©2000-2014 iText Group NV (AGPL-version)"
      xmp:CreateDate="2014-05-16T17:04:59+01:00"
      xmp:CreatorTool="My program using iText"
      xmp:ModifyDate="2014-05-16T17:04:59+01:00"
      xmp:MetadataDate="2014-05-16T17:04:59+01:00">
      <dc:description>
        <rdf:Alt>
          <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">This example shows how to add metadata</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Alt>
      </dc:description>
      <dc:creator>
        <rdf:Seq>
          <rdf:li>Bruno Lowagie</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Seq>
      </dc:creator>
      <dc:subject>
        <rdf:Bag>
          <rdf:li>Metadata</rdf:li>
          <rdf:li>iText</rdf:li>
          <rdf:li>PDF</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Bag>
      </dc:subject>
      <dc:title>
        <rdf:Alt>
          <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">Hello World example</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Alt>
      </dc:title>
    </rdf:Description>
  </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

You recognize:

```
<dc:subject>
    <rdf:Bag>
        <rdf:li>Metadata</rdf:li>
        <rdf:li>iText</rdf:li>
        <rdf:li>PDF</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Bag>
</dc:subject>
```

But do you see:

```
pdf:Keywords="Metadata, iText, PDF"
```

You need that part too.

This is a screen shot **with** that part:

[image]

When I remove `pdf:Keywords="Metadata, iText, PDF`", I can reproduce your problem:

[image]

This proves that your problem is caused by your XMP file, **not** by iText.

Comment: Ok no problem it is my own suggestion why we cant trim the string content  before assigning to corresponding field with default separator for example `value = value.TrimStart(';');`,`value = value.TrimEnd(';');` and `value = value.Trim();`

Comment: No `;` is added by iText. There is no `;` in the PDF. The `;` is added by Adobe Reader when viewing the document. Hence, I assume (or suggest) that you don't direct this remark to iText, but to Adobe.